# Carto https basemap 500 Domain not found

Tags: leaflet, carto, tiles, offline

I have an issue with calling this tile server:

`https://cartodb-basemaps-abcd.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/13/4505/2407.png`

it says `500 (Domain not found)`, yet I can see the tiles on the screen. The issue I have is that I want to use the tiles in the leaflet-offline-map API, but this error causes issues and I can't download the tiles.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domains for the URL are a, b, c or d, but it seems you're substituting them incorrectly in the URL.

You can use:

`https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/13/4505/2407.png`

being `{s}` any of (a,b,c,d), for example:

`https://cartodb-basemaps-b.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/13/4505/2407.png`